# Lost UK paper driving licence after residing in France for 22 years

Tags: driving

I was asked to show my driving licence at work today to drive a hire car for some VIPs. I have looked and realize I haven't seen it for months. How on earth do I replace a pink UK paper licence I've had since 1981, without losing the right to drive which is absolutely essential for everything I do here? I've been twice to see if I should change it and was told it was okay, so never bothered getting a French licence. Can anybody advise me on this?